# Sampling too soon after MUX switching channel

Tags: noise, multiplexer

I'm confused with noise created by switching channels on a MUX. My supervisor on my bachelor thesis warned me about sampling too soon after a channel switch, because noise could make the voltage values inaccurate when sampled by an ADC.

The MUX I'm using is the [SparkFun Analog/Digital MUX Breakout - CD74HC4067](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9056)

This is the oscilloscope picture from a channel switch where "channel 1" is \$\approx\text{0V}\$ to \$\approx\text{2.7V}\$ on the next channel.

[image: oscilloscope when switching from \approx 0V to \approx 2.7V]

In the [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/cd74hc4067.pdf) on the component CD74HC4067 it says (on page 4):

[image: Propagation Delay Time]

Am I completely misunderstanding the term "switching noise"? Because I can't really see values that will be big enough to cause a problem. I'll be sampling after approx >7ms.

Comment: Who said that you will have a problem with 7ms after the switch? 7ms might qualify as "not too soon" in your case.

Comment: This is why chose 7ms, didnt think i was going to have a problem. The issue is i don't really understand where the noise should be or if the MUX is actually creating some because of the switching

Comment: There is no noise - either your supervisor is wrong or you have misquoted or misunderstood him. It's all about settling time.

Comment: Consider taking the average of multiple samples.  Some processors have specifications where, in order to improve the number of significant bits, you need to set up the processors' hardware to automatically take the average of multiple samples.  That or you could average individual samples in your code.  Having a 12 bit ADC only provide 4 bits of accuracy for a single fast conversion is not that unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least FIVE sources of "noise" in an analog multiplexer.

1) noise from the VDD supplies, that noise appearing on gates of the MOSFET switches; assume each gate is 100pF capacitance from the VDD into your signal path

2) noise from the digital control signals (MicroController outputs are never quiet, unless you shut off the MCU clocking); these 1 nanosecond transients (0.5 volt amplitude) inject charge and that charge explores **all** possible paths back to the MCU. This exploration makes the inductors ring, in GND pin, in VDD pin, and elsewhere. Even in clean-VDD situations, this need-a-return-path charge movement causes the VDD and the GND to constantly be ringing

3) charge injection from switching; to reduce this impact, have very low source and load impedances; this means have capacitors on both input and output pins

4) the "noise" from not yet accurately settled channel switching; every TAU of setting provides another NEPER, or 8.6 dB of improved accuracy (about 1.6 bits better ENOB)

5) the genuine FET channel thermal/Johnson/Boltzmann random noise; 1 K ohm Ron provides 4 nanovolts per rootHertz; a 1 Kohm channel and 159pF Cload is a 159 nanosecond Tau and is exactly 1MHz bandwidth. A 1 MHz bandwidth at 4 nanoVolts/rtHz becomes 4,000 nanoVolts (4nV * sqrt(1,000,000)) or 4 microVolts RMS noise floor. [there is a PI/2 error here; you may ignore that for now; this factor comes from the gradual attenuation of any 1-pole RC filter]

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how much capacitance is on the MUX output and how long the ADC needs the value to be stable before beginning the acquisition and conversion. The switching times you see there are not really relevant in most situations.

If you have a 100n capacitor on the output and the MUX has a worst-case resistance of 270 ohm, then to settle within 1/2 LSB for a 16-bit converter will take around 12 time constants, so about 300usec. If you have a 10K resistor and 100n the time would be about 12ms.

Your analog anti-aliasing filters should go in front of the multiplexer, of course.

---

There is also a small amount of switching noise that will be injected into the output when it switches. Analog switches, especially the ones aimed at precision analog applications, often include a specification for charge injection. The package of charge will be delivered to the output and can cause a relatively large change in output voltage, however it will die off with the same time constant as indicated above.

[image]

This is caused by imbalance in the internal capacitances of the MOSFET switches, coupling a switching transient to the analog switch connections when they are driven on and off.